# how convert structured text file to xml file api

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csv

I have a structured text file, each information is located by its position(offset) and length, for example, this line is taken from a text file:

```
H00VLS1    1200    32D1    20140602080524WIRE SPEC DATA
```

and here is the rules to extract data:

```
HEADER_ID        length(3)  offset(1)
PRODUCT_NO       length(15) offset(4)
SORT_FIELD       length(9)  offset(19)
SUFFIX           length(9)  offset(28)
PERSON_CODE      length(5)  offset(33)
PROCESS_DATE     length(8)  offset(38)
MAINTENANCE_DATE length(8)  offset(46)
```

finally, after applying this rules we get this data:

```
HEADER_ID   PRODUCT_NO   SORT_FIELD   SUFFIX     PERSON_CODE   PROCESS_DATE   MAINTENANCE_DATE
H00         VLS1  1200   32D1         20140      60208         0607WIRE       SPEC DA
```

generated xml file:

```
<header>
<header_id>H00</header_id>
<product_no>VLS1  1200</product_no>
<sort_feild>32D1</sort_feild>
<suffix>20140</suffix>
<person_code>60208</person_code>
<process_date>0607WIRE</process_date>
<maintenance_date>SPEC DA</maintenance_date>
</header>
```

Now my question is there a C# class or api to convert my text file to an xml or json file, based on length and offset rules ?

Comment: Sure - `FileStream` and LINQ to XML (or `XmlDocument`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to do what you want using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387090.aspx):

```
    // Read txt file into an array of strings.
    string[] source = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\mypath\text.txt");

    // Construct xml from above source file. Use helper method to split string.
    XElement cust = new XElement("Root",
        from str in source
        let fields = SplitLine(str)
        select new XElement("header",
            new XElement("header_id", fields[0]),
            new XElement("product_no", fields[1]),
            new XElement("sort_field", fields[2]),
            new XElement("suffix", fields[3]),
            new XElement("person_code", fields[4]),
            new XElement("process_date", fields[5]),
            new XElement("maintenance_date", fields[6])
            )
        );
```

You can easily split every line of the txt file using `substring` function with offset - 1, length as indices:

```
public static string[] SplitLine(string str)
{
     string[] s = new string[7] { 
         str.Substring(0, 3),
         str.Substring(3, 15),
         str.Substring(18, 9),
         str.Substring(27, 9),
         str.Substring(32, 5),
         str.Substring(37, 8),
         str.Substring(45, 8)
     };
     return s;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to process your file and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to convert the results into XML.